# Get only some entries of a table from another webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make an automation app that wants to select only some of the entries in a table from another page and write those entries in a table. The problem is that my source HTML (from which I am fetching data) does not have `id` attribute set on them, so I am really getting a hard time getting **only** some fields. My HTML looks like:

```
<section id="file">
    <div class="section-title">
        <h4>File Details</h4>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" />
            <col width="*" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <th>File name</th>
            <td><span class="mono">1636d19724ac08f3c48235e27c2bc26d</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>File size</th>
            <td><span class="mono">67584 bytes</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>File type</th>
            <td><span class="mono">PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>CRC32</th>
            <td><span class="mono">96AE0B79</span></td>
        </tr>

</table>
</section>
```

My jQuery script currently looks like:

```
$("#first").load("report.html #file table:nth-child(2)");
```

(I have given my destination HTML file different tags with id's like `first`, so I intend to write many of these). This line tries to fetch only one value, that is, the `File Name` table row. 
But I am getting the entire table.

Where am I wrong?
Any help.
Thanks.

Comment: @BenM It doesnt. Checkout: http://api.jquery.com/load/ Scroll down to 'Loading Page Fragments' section.

Comment: Are you sure about the path to `report.html` ?

Comment: You have an extra space before `table:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: you are probably supposed to do `table tr:nth-child(2)` In fact `nth-child(1)` if you want to get the file name. Example: http://jsbin.com/dewijoceni/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should check your selector. Try this:

```
$("#first").load("report.html #file table tr:nth-child(1) td").text();
```